# Zsh: start new prompt in command mode (vi mode)

Tags: command-line, zsh

Is there a way to start each new prompt in Vi "command mode" instead of "insert mode". I do not want to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> every time.

Comment: what do you mean by starting each new prompt

Comment: @Bharat They want the default mode of the command line editor to be "command mode" rather than "insert mode" when using Vi command editing mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this is actually found in the `zshzle` (or `zshall`) manual:

```
zle-line-init() { zle -K vicmd; }
zle -N zle-line-init
```

This will always put the command line into Vi command mode for each new prompt.

Comment: Just [`info zsh zle-line-init`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-zle_002dline_002dinit) (or `i` and then `zle-line-init` with completion within `info`). Using `man` for manuals this size is masochism.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks! Remember, I'm not a `zsh` user ;-)